# svg inside svg translates by browser resize

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a svg and I am adding different svg elements to it:

```
<svg> .... <rect or circle and so on </svg>
```

What I did was I loaded an icon with an svg library to one on my circles. Everything was fine until I changed my browser size and I noticed the svg icons are moving outside of my circle.

```
<svg> <circle> <g> <svg ....the icon> </g> </svg>
```

Looks like because I have 2 svgs nested, the icon is moving, and the offset for it is maybe the browser!

How can I fix that? I need to load my images like this:

```
Image1 = require('svg-react-loader?name=Image1!./svgFiles/default.svg');
React.createElement(Image1, {});
```

Comment: please provide a MCVE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We need to see a working example ([mcve]). It is hard to help you debug code we cannot see.  This help page may also be worth a read: [ask].